# in_array not working with dynamic ip address

Tags: php, arrays, magento

I have a helper function in that i m checking is ip in array but return always false.even ip is in array.

```
public function checkIP(){  
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
    $remoteIP =  Mage::helper('core/http')->getRemoteAddr();
    $status = Mage::getStoreConfig('nutripayment/general/active',$storeId); 

    $ip = Mage::getStoreConfig('nutripayment/general/ipadd',$storeId); 
    $ips = explode(',', $ip);
    var_dump($ips);
    var_dump($remoteIP);
    exit;
    if(in_array($remoteIP,$ips)){
        var_dump($remoteIP);exit;
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}
```

can anyone help me to resolve this.

Comment: What is the output of the `var_dump`s?

Answer (score 0):

Did yo leave the exit in there on purpose to handle the var_dump?  Here is your current code.

```
if(in_array($remoteIP,$ips)){
    var_dump($remoteIP);
    exit;
    return true;
}
```

How about changing it to

```
if(in_array($remoteIP,$ips)){
    var_dump($remoteIP);
    return true;
    exit;
}
```